# How come you don't need to name exception php?

Tags: php, exception

When you throw an exception you don't name it, why is this? I read that is an object, don't you need to assign an object to a variable? e.g.

```
throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
```

And how does this work:

```
catch (Exception $e){
//do something
}
```

What does Exception $e mean, is this some kind of shorthand for declaring an object?

Comment: It's telling PHP to catch thrown Exception objects, and in this case, refer to that caught object as `$e`. You can then do `$e->getCode()` to get the Exception code for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throw` is just a keyword that you need to follow by an object of type `Exception` or another class based on the `Exception` class. The `Exception` class constructor takes a `string` argument which instantiates an `Exception` object with that exception message.

The `catch` block functions basically as a method that is called with the `Exception` object after the `throw` keyword. The catch block takes an `Exception` object as a parameter which in this case is named `$e` inside the `catch block`.

This is the `Exception` class `construct`:

`public __construct ([ string $message = "" [, int $code = 0 [, Exception $previous = NULL ]]] )`

[Read more about the Exception class here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php)

If you want you can even name the `Exception` object before throwing it:

```
try {
    $ex = new Exception('Test exception.');
    throw $ex;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Cacthed exception.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an object. `catch (Exception $e) {}` means "Catch any exception object that is of class "Exception" or has it as one of its parents, and store it in the variable `$e`".

Then in the `{}` block you can deal with it accordingly (for example, write `echo $e->getMessage();`.

You can catch any kind of exceptions - for example, `catch (InvalidArgumentException $e)` will catch only exceptions of type `InvalidArgumentException`, while `catch (Exception $e)` will catch any type of exception, including `InvalidArgumentException`.